# How to disable any particular menu in windows application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows

Please check below screen shot

[image]

For Example:

I am having a String. Value of that string is "Bank"
I need some logic that disable the menu with name "Bank"

I hope you got my question.

Comment: Is this your app, Do you have Source code of it? Or you want to try hack someone else app ?

Comment: yes i have a code for it but these menus that you can see in screen shot is static. It means it is added from design view of my application.

Comment: please refer updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is VERY vague, this answer might be wrong. But what I think you want is to disable a menu item at certain times.

```
 menuitem.IsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: but it disabled whole menu. i need to disable only "Tax Head" in "Masters".

Comment: @AijazChauhan - just replace menuItem with the name of the subMenuItem

Answer (score 0):

You need to just set the `Enabled` property of your menuItem `Zone` to `false`

Try This:

```
yourMenuItem.Enabled = false;
```

here `yourMenuItem` is the `name` of the menu item `zone`

Answer (score 0):

Can you find name of your menu ITEM inside menu.Open Form in design view select your menu item and hit F4 (to get properties window) on properties you should be able to see name of your item. You can try hide that on properites menu.
Or you need somewhere in code behind to do that through code.

Here is ss of it[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question

Answer is like below

```
 foreach (ToolStripMenuItem d in fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
 {
    if (d.Name == "saveToolStripMenuItem")
    {
       d.Enabled = true;
    }
 }
```